# Pasar un objeto entre clases

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, objeto

estoy aprendiendo interfaz gráfica en java con JFrame y quiero pasar un objeto de un frame el cual crea una serie al frame principal donde puedo ver diferentes objetos.

**Pense en usar un getter** para que el return sea del tipo Serie , pero al aplicar el método en el frame "padre" o principal , no cumplo con los parámetros del método que es justamente tener un objeto.

**Pense también en usar un setter** pero lo veo inútil porque no quiero asignar un valor , sino mas bien utilizar el que ya cree en el otro frame.

**Por ultimo se me ocurrió tener un objeto** ya creado en el frame principal y refundirlo en mi frame principal pero creo que eso me dejaría 2 objetos iguales y una enorme perdida de eficiencia y recursos .

**Actualizo la pregunta para mostrarles parte del codigo:

***El Frame Principal con el jButton crear Serie***

private void Crear_serie_butomActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
  Creacion_de_Serie serie_creada=new Creacion_de_Serie();
  serie_creada.setVisible(true);
  //  Creacion_de_Serie.Llevar_Serie(objeto); 
 // El metodo llevar serie me trae el objeto de la otra interfaz

El frame secundario (clase Serie_Creada)
```

private void butom_aceptarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String nom,crea,gen;
        int tem;

```
    crea=this.txt_Creador.getText();
    nom=this.txt_Nombre.getText();
    tem=Integer.parseInt(this.txt_numero_tempo.getText());
    gen=this.txt_Genero.getText();

    Serie sere1=new Serie(nom, tem,false,gen, crea);
    Llevar_Serie(sere1);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La Serie fue agregada" );

    this.setVisible(false);
```

Gracias, nuevamente !!

Comment: Santiago bienvenido a [es.so] ! Mi primera recomendación es que le eches un vistazo al [tour] y así ver el funcionamiento del sitio. También te aconsejo que pongas el código de lo que has intentado hasta ahora en tu pregunta dandole al botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/196010/edit), mas información aquí [ask]

Comment: Lo normal es usar objetos para trasladar datos entre clases, no te preocupes por la eficiencia y recursos, el usar java ya es una gran perdida de los mismos.